# How to update an existing row in BigQuery

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-api-nodejs-client

I am just getting started with BQ and its Node.js client, and for my use case, I would like to insert or update rows depending on if they already exist based on a unique identifier that is stored in one of the columns.

I don't see any examples in the node client repository of how to update a row instead of injecting.

So in other words, I want to query my table to see if the "id" field already matches x. If it exists, I want to replace the row, if it doesn't, I want to inject it.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a `Bigquery` [merge](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement) query with the `NodeJs` [client](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/main/samples/query.js) :

```sql
MERGE dataset.Inventory T
USING dataset.NewArrivals S
ON T.product = S.product
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET quantity = T.quantity + S.quantity
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (product, quantity) VALUES(product, quantity)
```

The `merge` queries allows updating the element if it exists in `Bigquery`, or otherwise insert it.

If you are interested I written an [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/remove-duplicates-in-bigquery-batch-pipeline-with-airflow-and-dataflow-2e7da5772c4d) showing merge query and how to remove duplicates in batch pipelines using `BigQuery`

Comment: You’re welcome. I updated my answer with a link to an article I written previously. I hope it can help you. If the answer is useful for you, may you upvote ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48177344/294632)

So apparently BigQuery is not designed to behave like a database. Instead of updating existing rows, you keep appending data as new rows and later use a query to clean up the table by removing duplicates like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130324/bigquery-delete-statement-to-remove-duplicates)