# remove duplicated row from BigQuery created

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I have a BigQuery table that contain duplicate rows with the same values except for a column of timestamp called CreatedAt

```
id    | CreatedAt                      | value1 | value2 |
1     | 2023-11-24 01:08:51.388158 UTC | ABC    | 123    |
2     | 2023-11-25 03:16:51.388158 UTC | DEF    | 456    |
3     | 2023-11-25 03:20:35.388158 UTC | JKL    | 111    |
1     | 2023-11-24 01:08:55.388158 UTC | ABC    | 123    | 
2     | 2023-11-25 03:17:03.388158 UTC | DEF    | 456    |
4     | 2023-11-25 03:21:07.388158 UTC | ZZZ    | 990    |
```

I would wish to remove duplicated value created at the later timestamp

```
    id    | CreatedAt                      | value1 | value2 |
    1     | 2023-11-24 01:08:51.388158 UTC | ABC    | 123    |
    2     | 2023-11-25 03:16:51.388158 UTC | DEF    | 456    |
    3     | 2023-11-25 03:20:35.388158 UTC | JKL    | 111    |
    4     | 2023-11-25 03:21:07.388158 UTC | ZZZ    | 990    |
```

Is there an efficient way to remove duplicates based on the timestamp (only remove rows with timestamp at CreatedAt column) assuming I have over 10k of duplicated rows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BigQuery - DELETE statement to remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130324/bigquery-delete-statement-to-remove-duplicates)

Comment: how do you determine which is the duplicate one? the first one by createdAt or those after it?
If it is not necessary to delete, I think you should create a new table containing unique rows instead of deleting these duplicated rows because createdAt field should mean something if they're changed